# Need help with application of Hardy-Littlewood inequality (Marcinkiewicz space and distribution functions)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am going over this work [here](http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol39/vol39pp361-388.pdf). 
[image]

I couldn't understand the equality where the Hardy-Littlewood inequality is used. I think $\delta$ here is a weight so we can take it to be $1$ for simplicity. Would appreciate any help. I think this has something to do with Marcinkiewicz space and distribution functions but I've not been able to find a useful theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any use of any Hardy-Littlewood inequality here. You have a measure space $(Q,\delta^\alpha \,dx\,dt)$, which has finite total measure. I will denote the measure by $\mu$ for simplicity. The assumption (2.7) says that $u$ is in the weak $L^{\hat q}( d\mu)$ space. Then it's just a matter of interpolation to  get that $u\in L^q( d\mu)$ for every $1\le q<\hat q$. The computations use the layercake formula for $L^q( d\mu)$ norm, such as 
$$
\int |u|^q \,d\mu = -\int_0^\infty k^q  \,d\mu(\{|u|>k\}) = 
q\int_0^\infty k^{q-1} \mu(\{|u|>k\})\,dk
$$
See formula (9) in [this post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/), or any real analysis book dealing with $L^p$ spaces in detail.

We have an upper estimate for $\mu(\{|u|>k\})$ to use in the above integral. But it's  awkward to use it when $k$ is small, so we apply it only where $|u|>\lambda$, accounting for small values of $|u|$ separately. Then optimize for $\lambda$.